# Is there a way to count every call to sql.Exec?

Tags: go

I am writing a backend in go for an angular application. I want to log for every request how many database queries were executed.

For this, I want to increment an integer every time sql.Exec is called. How do I do this without manually adding it to every single place I use sql.Exec? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You could wrap `sql.Exec` in a method and do all increments in that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I do this without manually adding it to every single place I use sql.Exec?

Wrap your SQL access object. For example:

```
type MyDB struct {
    *sql.DB
    count int
}

func (db *MyDB) Exec(query string, args ...interface{}) (sql.Result,error) {
    db.count++
    return db.DB.Exec(query, args...)
}
```

Then use your wrapped type everywhere. This will (probably) mean updating a lot of code to use an interface, rather than a `*sql.DB` variable.

The only other option is to write a wrapper around the SQL driver (rather than the client).  But you'd use the same approach.  This method requires a bit more understanding of Go's `sql` internals.

Comment: If that's true, then I'm glad I never use Ruby. Magic is evil.

Answer (score -5):

> How do I do this without manually adding it to every single place I use sql.Exec?

Not at all. Go offers no magic. If you want things done you must do them.